# Using VS2010 as an IDE and using MSVC 2005 as a compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wanted to use VS2010 and an IDE and using MSVC 2005 as a compiler, how can I do that?

Comment: Why? What you ask for is possible, but do you have a project that *really requires* the VC++ 2005 compiler? Why not use at least the 2008 SP1 version (15.00.30729.01)?

Comment: @in silico yes I have a project that only requires VC++ 2005

Comment: @lamia: What I mean is that your project may also compile on VC++ 2008. Have you considered the 2008 version? I ask because the Windows 7 SDK comes with the VC++ 2008 compilers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 includes the capability of multi-targeting C++ projects (native or managed) using the [Platform Toolset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx) option.  The built-in support is for v100 (VS2010) and v90 (VS2008).

See: [C++ Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) which shows how to extend the feature to support v80 (VS2005).

See these [special MSDN instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx) for managed projects.

Comment: Interesting. This made me discover that Intel C++ compiler is integrated with msbuild using xml files in platform toolsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a makefile project to compile anything non-normative. We do this to compile with mingw and cygwin, but it will work the same way for any compiler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx